# A bit challenging integration. (at least for me its challenging)

Tags: calculus, integration, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-physics

Hello everybody I am trying to solve this integral. I show you how far I 've gone.
$\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac {e^{-i\vec{k}.\vec{x}}e^{-ik^{\circ}x_{\circ}}\delta(k^{\circ})}{k^2-\mu^2}d^2kdk^{\circ}$.
Taking to plane polar coordinates

$=\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{0}\displaystyle\int^{2\pi}_{0}\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac {e^{-i|\vec{k}| |\vec{x}|\cos\theta}e^{-ik^{\circ}x_{\circ}}\delta(k^{\circ})}{k^{\circ 2} -|\vec{k}|^2-\mu^2}|\vec{k}|dkd\theta dk^{\circ}$.

Where 
$k^2=k^{\circ 2} -|\vec{k}|^2 $.

Now
solving delta function we get.

$=\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{0}\displaystyle\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac {e^{-i|\vec{k}| |\vec{x}|\cos\theta}}{-|\vec{k}|^2-\mu^2}|\vec{k}|dkd\theta$.

Now bring in Bessel function

$=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n \frac{2\pi}{n!n!}\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{0}\left(\frac{|\vec{k}||\vec{x}|}{2}\right)^{2n}\frac {1}{|\vec{k}|^2+\mu^2}|\vec{k}|dk\\$.

Nowwwww I don't know what to do.........

Comment: @graydad it was possible with your help. here is what i ve been trying to do.

Comment: please look at the series expansion for $J_0$. You're have it in principle...

Comment: @graydad $a=kx$ here

Comment: @ZohaibAarfi ah I see. What about the $2\pi$ part?

Comment: @graydad its there you didn't see it. hehehehehe

Comment: $J_0(kx)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{kx}{2}\right)^{2n}$, i don,t see the problem...
the real problem is the integral over $|k|$